# updated value of asp.net label not reflected on java script variable

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net label , label2 which is in an ajax update panel.

```
<div id="Div1" class="InsertBar">
   <asp:Label ID="Label2" 
            runat="server" Visible="true" Font-Bold="true">
   </asp:Label>    
      <asp:GridView>
        <!-- my gridview template and columns -->
      </asp:GridView>
   </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

This update panel is displayed in a  jquery dialog.
         The jquery dialog is opened on button click event.

I am assigning a value for the label *label2* in asp.net code behind on each button click.

I am trying to access *label2* in the javascript code using the following code.

```
 var newtitle = $('#<%=Label2.ClientID%>').text();
```

The javascript function is below . The function is called from asp.net code behind

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ViewModelPopup1() {

            var newtitle = $('#<%=label2.ClientID%>').text();

            $(Div1).dialog('option', 'title', newtitle);

        }
   </script>
```

The problem I have is , for the first time the asp.net button is clicked the javascript variable *new title* gets assigned to the asp.net `label2`.  But on subsequent button clicks the javascript variable newtitle does not get updated . Any suggestions on how I can update the javascript variable to the asp.net label on each button click ?

Just my thoughts. I have the asp.net label within an ajax update panel. Should I also use any ajax for the javascript ???

Comment: Can we see the entire javascript/jquery function that you having issues with? It may help a little more.

Comment: I updated the code .. But am not sure if it would be helpful. Let me know if anything is not clear. I will try my best

Comment: Can we also see your button click code?

Comment: If this your true code `$(Div1).dialog('option', 'title', newtitle);`. You need to access `Div1` like `'#Div1`', otherwise you will get a null value. Otherwise I'm not sure what the problem would be. I would stick to keeping everything either client or server side though, that might be causing a problem, but again, I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey Brett ! Thank you !  The problem  actually is that the var newtitle doesnt get the updated value of the of the asp.net label . The label is within an ajax update panel . I was wondering if the javascript code should also use some kind of ajax ??